# Domain not working with WWW prefix

Tags: .htaccess, cpanel

i added in .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

but not working with www version

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

it will permanently redirect https://example.com to https://www.example.com

Comment: i tried this also but same thing happen
This site can’t be reached

www.qeo.ca’s server DNS address could not be found.

Answer (score 0):

```
60/6708# host www.qeo.ca
Host www.qeo.ca not found: 3(NXDOMAIN)
```

I don't think you have an issue with the **.htaccess** file but rather with your DNS configuration. So update your DNS records so the domain will point to your cPanel server's ip address.

If your computer is not able to resolve the host **www.qeo.ca** or **qeo.ca** then it's pretty obvious that you won't be able to access it in your browser. Your qeo.ca has these nameservers:

```
Name servers:
    dns1.registrar-servers.com
    dns2.registrar-servers.com
```

So go to your registrar, edit your DNS zone and update the records. Keep in mind that after DNS update it could take a few hours until you'll be able to actually access your website.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

The above code worked for me, hope it helps.